# Where can I find (plain) Ramen noodles?

Tags: shopping, noodles

I recently thought about trying to make the Chicken Ramen recipe from [Wagamama](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagamama), however I will need to know how to get the correct ingredients from the best sources. I don't know any good sources to get the right noodles for making the Ramen.

Where should I look to acquire good-quality Ramen noodles for a recipe such as this?

Here's the recipe in the book I took a snapshot of.

**EDIT:** I found a website where you can purchase them from

> http://www.theasiancookshop.co.uk/fresh-ramen-noodles-400g-3570-p.asp

[image: Chicken Ramen Recipe]

Comment: Second paragraph rewritten because this isn't a shopping/polling/pricing site; we can help inform you where to look  for something but that is the hard limit for shopping questions.

Comment: It helps to let us know what country you live in when asking where to find products.

Comment: I live in the UK.

Comment: Plain wheat noodles would be normal spaghett(i/ini) u can get from the supermarket

Comment: But Ramen noodles and Spaghetti noodles are much different

Comment: Buy a few packages of Top Ramen, and just throw out the seasoning packet. http://www.target.com/p/maruchan-174-ramen-noodle-soup-chicken-flavor-3oz/-/A-14767986

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Ramen noodles" are a predominantly North American term for what the Japanese call "Chinese Noodles" (*Chukamen*, which I've also seen spelled *Yuukamen*).

In practice, you can use any wheat noodle that's made with eggs or *[kansui](http://www.rameniac.com/wiki/kansui/)*, including *lamian* or *mee pok*, or even buckwheat noodles (notably *soba*). Noodles made *without* either of those are not recommended.

It does not matter which of the above you use, although the *Chukamen* varieties are the more traditional. Much like pasta, it's largely a matter of personal preferences and how you want it to come out in terms of texture and appearance.

You'll find a wide variety of all of these noodles in dried or fresh form at any Asian supermarket or grocery store. Across Canada there's a chain called [T&T](http://www.tnt-supermarket.com/en/). You should have no trouble finding some Asian grocery stores in your region with a phone book or maybe Google or Yelp.

Comment: But I live in the UK, is there any locals where I can get them?

Comment: @lolwut: We aren't a directory service. Look up "Asian grocery" in your phone book or Google.

Comment: @MacMac - you can make your own, esp. if you have a pasta roller, as well.  To replicate the kansui effect, you can bake baking soda (that's not an error), which converts sodium bicarbonate to sodium carbonate, which is a stronger alkaline.  This replicates the chemistry of the local water that gives ramen its distinctive characteristics.  A Google search on "homemade ramen" will help with recipes and instructions.

Answer (score 2):

A larger asian grocer will carry a few varieties of dried/fresh noodles labelled "Ramen" - some will be plain wheat noodles, some will be alkali processed (which is what you want). The ingredient list on the package will tell you what kind actually is in the package - if it is alkali processed, the alkali will either be plainly named, or listed as E number 500 and/or 501.

Answer (score 2):

Buy yourself a few packages of cheap Ramen Noodle Soup. They can be found at most grocery stores for between $0.10 and $0.50 USD per package.

Boil them in a little bit of water, but don't add the seasoning packet. Rinse and drain, then you have your noodles!

Here's an example: http://www.target.com/p/maruchan-174-ramen-noodle-soup-chicken-flavor-3oz/-/A-14767986

Comment: The "plain" ramen instant noodles sold ten or so in a package at asian grocery stores are of a much better quality than the ones that come as "instant soup" with the flavor packets. So much better in fact that once I discovered them I never again purchased the normal instant ramen soup packets.

Answer (score 0):

There are many Asian supermarkets in the UK, and if you live in London there are markets in Brewer Street and The Japan centre on Shaftesbury Avenue.

There is also an on-line Japanese site...

http://www.japanesekitchen.co.uk/